# 'I'd appreciate you copied me in the e-mail'?

Tags: phrases

Is it correct to say: 'I'd appreciate you copied me in the e-mail?' If not, then why and what is the correct phrase?

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE. It isn't correct, but we can't tell you what the proper phrasing should be as you haven't told us what you are trying to say, and what led you to believe the proposed phrasing was or wasn't right. Please [edit] your post to include this information. I also strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* say it; in conversation the ellipsis wouldn't really be noticed, but if you were to write it, then it would be far better to include the missing words

> I'd appreciate it if you copied me in the e-mail?

which kind of works grammatically - but sounds less of a polite request & more of a rebuke for some earlier aberrant behaviour.

It's also not a question.

Perhaps re-cast it as

> I'd appreciate it if you could copy me in the email

or even just

> Could you copy me in the email?

which **is** now a question.

There's still something about using 'appreciate' that sounds like you're slightly annoyed.

The phrase "copy me in" would typically be understood to mean 'when you send the email, set my address in the CC: field.'
I don't think anyone would be confused by the phrase in a modern office environment.